# How to check Trino version with SQL query?

Tags: sql, version, presto, trino

Is there a SQL query to check the version of Trino? Couldn't find it in the [docs](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`version`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/system.html?highlight=version#version) function:

```
SELECT version()
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to check which Trino version is running on AWS Athena v3:

```
SELECT version()
```

Gives the error: `FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND`

---

If you try to query `system.runtime.nodes` directly:

```
SELECT node_version
FROM system.runtime.nodes
```

Gives the error: `Queries of this type are not supported`